# Dynamic div swapping using php/jquery resulting in a page recursion

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on making a dynamically loaded website using some php code to swap out content from various other files. While on top of that I am using jquery to beautify this swap out.

Relevant PHP:

```
<?php
// Set the default name
    $page = 'home';

// Specify some disallowed paths
    $disallowed_paths = array('js.php','css.php','index.php');

if (!empty($_GET['page'])){
    $tmp_page = basename($_GET['page']);
        // If it's not a disallowed path, and if the file exists, update $page
    if (!in_array($tmp_page, $disallowed_paths) && file_exists("{$tmp_page}.php"))
    $page = $tmp_page;
}

// Include $page
if(!file_exists("$page.php")){
    $page = 'home';
}
else{
include("$page.php");}
?>
```

Relevant jquery:

```
$(function (a) {
    var $body           = $('body'),
    $dynamo         = $('.dynamo'),
    $guts           = $('.guts');

$body.fadeIn('slow');

if (history.pushState) {
    var everPushed  = false;

    $dynamo.on('click', 'a', function (b) {
        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href');
        history.pushState(null,'',toLoad);
        everPushed = true;
        loadContent(toLoad);
        b.preventDefault();
    });

    $(window).bind('popstate', function () {
        if (everPushed) {
            $.getScript(location.href);
        }
        everPushed = true;
    });
} // otherwise, history is not supported, so nothing fancy here.

function loadContent(href) {
    $guts.hide('slow', function () {
        $guts.load(href, function () {
            $guts.show('slow');
        });
    });
}
a.preventDefault();
    });
```

1. What is happening is when I link to a page using ?page=about it will work but it will instead of just swapping out the content it will load the entire page including the content  inside the dynamically loaded div.
2. If I were to link straight to about.php  it would work beautifully with no fault whatsoever, but anybody who wanted to share that link http://example.com/about.php would get just the content with no css styling.
3. If I were to change the jquery in "loadContent" to:

   ```
   $guts.load(href + ' .guts', function () {
   ```

**EDIT 1**:

```
    , ' .guts'
```

to

```
    + ' .guts'
```

It would then work but any script, java, jquery, or the like would not work because it gets stripped out upon content load.

check out http://kazenracing.com/st3

**EDIT 2**:
It also seems to be that the site does not work properly in the wild either.
No background and none of the icons show up, but it still gets the general problem across.

I can fix that myself, it will just take some time. For now my focus is on the recursion problem.

**EDIT 3**: Site no longer needs to be worked on, problem never solved but we are letting that project go. So the link no longer is a valid URL.

Comment: add b.preventDefault to the begin of the click event function instead of after your load() call maybe

Comment: @BassJobsen

Same result unfortunately.